# How can I run iot devices on batteries effectively

Tags: power, batteries, esp8266, low-power

I am trying to make a gift for someone and I want to make a little thing that displays a cute message whenever a number is texted. I know how to connect an esp8266 to an AWS system so that messages from phone numbers can be received by the device.

My only worry is that batteries cannot supply power to the whole device for a reasonably long amount of time, I'm fine if the other person has to change batteries after a month minimum. What would be the best methods, from a hardware and software standpoint to ensure that the device lasts a long time on batteries?

I'm also looking for recommendations on what type of hardware to use to display the message, I'd prefer something that could balance the power needs, with something that looks good aesthetically.

Comment: use e-paper display and deep sleep. mod the esp module (if not using bare chip) to remove any LEDs, usb>serial adapters, LDOs, etc. Or just run it off of USB, so they aren't stuck with changing batteries ever. With batteries, you'll either have a long avg lag to get a message, or poor battery life, neither is a great gift.

Comment: @dandavis, all good advice, was worried that you might need to have longer lag though :(

Comment: Frame challenge: Are you sure it needs to use batteries? If you can just use a cheap little 5 V wall wart, that removes all your problems. This sounds like the kind of thing that you'd set up like a little photo frame, more than something that needs to be portable.

Comment: a gift with an AWS subscription ?

Answer (score 1):

Wifi's going to use a lot of power, for long battery life you'll need to use BTLE or something like that, and now you're running down your phone to connect to wifi or mobile data.

E-paper for the display or reflective LCD if e-paper costs too much.

If you can plug it into a USB socket somewhere that's probably a better solution.